# The naming of Java Class file

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm learning about the Java Class files. I know that when a Java source file(Source.java) get compiled, we get Source.class file. If this Source.java contains some inner interface, we will get Source.class and Source$inner-interface.class. This is understandable as explained in this link:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/05/10-points-about-class-file-in-java.html

However, what confuses me is that sometimes I get more than that:

**Source$1.class**

**Source$1$1.class**

**Source$1$2.class**

**Source$inner-interface.class**

Where do these *Source$1.class*, *Source$1$1.class* and *Source$1$2.class* come from? What do these $1, $1$1, $1$2 mean? Do they have anything to do with the static variable inside the source file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the anonymous inner classes defined inside the main class.